# Php/mysql query join

Tags: mysql, syntax

I am trying to implement a tag system for items.  The tags are contained in a table called tags and I have another table tagitem that links items to tags.  An item can have multiple tags. When I display the item, I would like to list all the tags.  My question is, is there any way to do this with one query?  If I join the items result to the tags table, either I get multiple records for one item (corresponding to the multiple tags) or if I include a group by tag, I get one record but only the first tag.

The other way would be to do a second query just to get the tags but that seems inefficient.

```
Item table
Id | name

Tag table
Id | tag

Tagitem table
Id|itemid|tagid

Php

$sql = "select i.*,ti.*,t.*
FROM 'items' i
LEFT JOIN 'tagitem' ti
ON i.id=ti.itemid
LEFT JOIN  'tag' t
On ti.tagid=t.id
WHERE i.id='2'";

//returns multiple records

$sql.="group by i.id";

//returns only first tag
```

Thx for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you give GROUP_CONCAT a try? How did it work out for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

You should be able to select your tags as a subquery and group them together to form an array.

```
SELECT
    Item.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT (Tags.tag SEPERATOR ',') AS tags
FROM
    Item
    LEFT JOIN Tagitem ON Tagitem.itemid = Item.Id
    LEFT JOIN Tag ON Tagitem.tagus = Tag.Id
WHERE
    Item.Id = 2
```

Give that a shot and let me know what happens. I'm guessing at the table structure a bit, so it may require some tweaking.

Comment: Thanks.  I got a syntax error: "right syntax to use near '(tags. SEPERATOR ',') AS tags FROM item LEFT JOIN `tagitem` t ON i.'  Not sure how to debug

Comment: In the GROUP_CONCAT statement did you mean Tags.tag or tag.tag

Comment: Sorry about that Tag.tag (tablename.fieldname), not Tags.tag. I always have a bit of trouble visualizing SQL on a DB I'm not actually working on. Also obviously you can use table and field aliases - I try to avoid them on here because I find it makes the code less readable.

Comment: Can you pull other fields from same table that you do not concatenate?

Comment: I believe so, you would just pull them as individual fields like Item.name. Assuming I'm following your question correctly...